# Playframework: DRY way to write I18n files

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization

Just want to make my translation file DRY, but when I try to something like:

```
  parent {
     child=Child!
  }
```

That doesn't work also:

```
  parent = {
     child=Child!
  }
```

It falls with `ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors: at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi`

But this works well:

```
  parent.child=Child!
```

But it's natural if we have 2 or more children with a parent to move them into parent block.

Comment: See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaI18N. Messages are in format properties - not json `files.summary=The disk {1} contains {0} file(s).`

Comment: sure, but how can I avoid duplication like this ?

`parent.child=Child!`
`parent.child2=Child2!`

Comment: There is no such thing out-of-the-box. But you can override the default behavior to use HOCON (or other configuration format) to do the internationalization. See https://github.com/marcospereira/play-i18n-hocon as an exercise (it is not ready/released).

Comment: Well, I see, thanks for the response

Comment: @marcospereira glad that I've inspired you to do that stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use play-i18n-hocon:

https://github.com/marcospereira/play-i18n-hocon

Keep in mind that, as stated at the docs, "this is not meant to be used as a drop-in replacement to default built-in module since Java Properties syntax is not compatible with HOCON."